# How to view a tinyblob object

Tags: php, mysql, deserialization

I'm currently working with an existing database that is Mysql, and the system is built in php.
For whatever reason the builder of this system chose to store some parts of the data in blobs.  One of them is a tiny blob.
In the database one of the records appears like this:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:3:"130";i:1;s:3:"182";}
```

This is viewable from the sql client I'm using.  It says it's a TINYBLOB(255).
I need to be able to figure out the correct structure used to set this up so that I could build my part.

It appears to me as if I'm not seeing a "true" representation of what the data structure is.

I ran this on the php side:

```
public function types_get() {
    $returnedTypes = $this->api->getReportTypes();
    echo($returnedTypes);
    $this->response($returnedTypes,REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}
```

It also produced this on the echo and response: `a:2:{i:0;s:3:"130";i:1;s:3:"182";}`
How would I be able to make it so I can see the true data as if it was a json string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This data string has been created with the `serialize()` function. You can convert it back to a native array with the matching `unserialize()` function:

```
$string = 'a:2:{i:0;s:3:"130";i:1;s:3:"182";}';
$data = unserialize($string);
print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array(
    [0] = 130
    [1] = 182
)
```